# C++ Socket recv() order error

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, udpclient

I want to create a RCON-sender in C++ for Jedi Academy Multiplayer Game. Everything works fine, only problem is that, when I read `recv()` from server, the order is not corrent sometimes!

```
std::vector<std::string> ReceiveLine() {
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    char* r = new char[1024];

    int i = 0;

    while (i < 40) {
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<1024; ++j) r[j]=0;
        if (recv(s_, r, 1024, 0) <= 12) {
            break;
        }
        ret.push_back(r+10);
        ++i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It prints like this:

```
map: mp/ffa3
num score ping name            lastmsg address               qport rate
  4     0    0 Alora                33                   bot  6145 16384
  5     0    0 Alora                33                   bot 22058 16384
  6     0    0 Alora                33                   bot 60636 16384
  7     0    0 Alora                33                   bot 18312 16384
  8     0    0 Alora                33                   bot 11812 16384
--- ----- ---- --------------- ------- --------------------- ----- -----
  0     0   22 test                  0   XX.XX.XXX.XXX:29070 65099 25000
  1     0    0 Alora                33                   bot  9234 16384
  9     0    0 Alora                33                   bot 27681 16384
 10     0    0 Alora                33                   bot 19116 16384
 11     0    0 Alora                33                   bot  3514 16384
  2     1    0 Alora                33                   bot 65099 16384
 12     0    0 Alora                33                   bot  5972 16384
  3     0    0 Alora                33                   bot 41129 16384
 13     0    0 Alora                33                   bot 30716 16384
```

It should be in order by num (Works in PHP)

Answer (score 2):

UDP does not guarantee ordered delivery.  There are lots of reasons why a datagram might arrive out of order.

Comment: how can PHP get it in order?

Comment: While that's true, and you do need to handle that situation, I wouldn't expect them to be that badly out of order in a repeatable way.  I suspect something else is wrong but cannot tell from this code snippet.  Are the packets you recv null-terminated strings?  Is it possible you're mixing two distinct streams?

Comment: yes, it should be null-terminated :) each line looks like `\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFprint [SOMETHING]\n`, and null until 1024. 
Socket: `s_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);` 
`sockaddr_in addr;` `addr.sin_family = AF_INET;` `addr.sin_port = htons(port);` `addr.sin_addr = *((in_addr *)he->h_addr);` `memset(&(addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);` And connect: `::connect(s_, (sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(sockaddr))` I use this one only, so I'm pretty sure, there is no conflicts, if you mean that :)

Comment: How much time is there between individual packet sends from the server?  (or said another way, what is the transmission rate if it's clocked?)